# Interacting with comments clears the post area in iOS app

Tags: bug, ios-app

Steps to reproduce:

Open any post and tap “add a comment”:

> [image]

Discard comment:

> [image]

Post body disappears:

> [image]

Same behavior after adding a comment.

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: Unknown (iPad7,3)
- OS Version: Version 11.2.1 (Build 15C153)